# How Do I Use Parcel JS with Express Middleware?

Tags: express, parceljs

I am trying to use a proxy server I created using Express JS, along with Parcel as my bundler. However, the middleware for an endpoint does not seem to be used. The browser remains on my webpage despite having a different URL address with the proper endpoint.
I am using the Parcel Watch command to bundle my entry files, which turns off Parcel's built-in dev server supposedly.
I am not sure what is going on. I can provide more info if needed. Any help is much appreciated!

server.js

```
import express from "express";
import routerHome from "../js/home_router";
import tickerRouter from "../js/ticker_router";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("dist"));
app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  next();
});

app.use("/", routerHome);
app.use("/ticker/:stock", tickerRouter);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Proxy listening on port:", PORT);
});
```

ticker_router.js file:

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
const tickerRouter = express.Router();

tickerRouter.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile(path.join("C:/Desktop/Ticqer2", "/dist/ticker.html"));
});

export default tickerRouter;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ticqer2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
 
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "",
    "watch": "parcel watch src/home.html src/ticker.html" ,
    "build": "parcel build --dist-dir public"
  
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cnbc-market": "^3.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "yahoo-finance2": "^2.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.10.2",
    "assert": "^2.1.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "parcel": "^2.10.2",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "url": "^0.11.3",
    "util": "^0.12.5"
  }
}
```